# How to set a listener in a RadioButton - Android

Tags: android, button

I have 3 RadioButton in 3 different LinearLayout. So, i can't have a RadioGroup.

How i can set the listener?
I try with the onCheckedListener:

```
RadioButton badChoise= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.badChoise);
badChoise.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                // i don't know what i need to set for buttonView, and isChecked



                }
```

if i set the onClickListener on my RadioButton , i have this error:

```
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at          
com.example.survey.Survey$1.onClick(Survey.java:73)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4377)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at    android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18044)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
10-28 13:06:10.893: E/AndroidRuntime(29179):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can someone help me?

Comment: you can use Checkbox instead of RadioButton.
you can also keep onCheckedChanged for CheckBox.
OnClick will be fine, too.

Comment: why the negative vote?

Comment: @Luca,what is your actual requirement can elaborate more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the RadioGroup and use the getCheckedRadioButtonId() function.

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom Listener to my radio buttons because my layout is incompatible with the RadioGroup

### First Create a Listener

```
OnClickListener listenerYear = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            month = v.getTag().toString(); //Add tags to your view to identify them
        }
    };
```

### Second add your buttons to the Listener one by one

```
RadioButton bt_JAN = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_JAN);
bt_JAN.setOnClickListener(listenerMonth);

RadioButton bt_FEB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_FEB);
bt_FEB.setOnClickListener(listenerMonth);
```

### Or use a loop to add them

```
for(int i=1;i<=12 ;i++){                
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("radio"+i, "id", getPackageName());                
            RadioButton bt = (RadioButton) findViewById(resID);
            bt.setOnClickListener(listenerMonth);
}
```

Comment: with the OnClickListener i have an error. see the edit question

Comment: You have to treat the checked status mannually, use OnClickListener instead a setOnCheckedChangeListener. Remember you don't have the RadioGroup